# I need to find the day of a date, i.e. monday, in python

Tags: python, date

I need a programme which can find out the day of any date.
all I know is that: (4/4, 6/6, 8/8, 10/10, 12/12, and the last day of February) fall on. in 2012 all these dates fell on a wednesday

Comment: `date.weekday()` perhaps?

Answer (score 6):

you want `date.weekday()`

`date(2002, 12, 4).weekday() == 2`

That shows that December 4th, 2002 was a Wednesday.

The date of the week is an integer where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 3):

One liner:

```
date(2012, 4, 4).strftime('%A')
>>> Wednesday
```